# How to convert cmdlet parameter (which is string) to any other type

Tags: c#, powershell-cmdlet

I want to pass parameter of custom type to my cmdlet. I declare parameter like this:

```cs
[Parameter(Position = 1)]
public StoreIdParameter Identity { get; set; }
```

But when I run cmdlet with parameter (like this: Get-Store VS) I get an exception:

> Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'.
>   Cannot convert the "VS" value of type
>   "System.String" to type
>   "R.Management.StoreIdParameter".

I created a constructor of StoreIdParameter, which accepts String but it didn't help. Should it be some type convertor from string to my type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. That was my mistake - I had constructor accepting string argument only in base class. I have added constructor to derived class (StoreIdParameter) with string argument and Powershell could create an instance of this class by calling proper constructor